# Convert object with delimited key into nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object with delimited key and I would like to convert this object into nested object. Anyone know a quick way to do in javascript or node?

For example:

```
    {
      'login': 'my login',
      'work.title': 'my title',
      'work.phone.mobile': '123',
      'work.phone.work': '456'
    }
```

convert to

```
   {
      login: 'my login',
      work: {
        title: 'my title',
        phone: {
          mobile: '123',
          work: '456'
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: But the first one is not even valid syntax...

Comment: @elclanrs, I figured and  I just updated my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument is the object you want to unflatten, the second argument is whether to modify `obj` or make a new object. The second argument is optional and defaults to `false`.

```
function unflatten(obj, modify){
    var i, j, keys, ref, result = modify ? obj : {};
    for(i in obj){
        for(keys = i.split('.'), ref = result, j = 0; j < keys.length - 1; j++)
            ref = (ref[keys[j]] = ref[keys[j]] || {});
        ref[keys[j]] = obj[i];
        if(modify && j)
            delete obj[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You mat try this

```
function toObj(str)
{
    var output = {};
    for(var key in str)
    {
        var nodes = key.split('.'), dest = output;
        if(nodes.length < 1) continue;
        for(var i = 0; i < (nodes.length - 1); ++ i)
        {
            var node = nodes[i];
            dest = (dest[node] === undefined) ? (dest[node] = {}) : dest[node];
        }
        dest[nodes[nodes.length - 1]] = str[key];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Call function

```
toObj({
    'login': 'my login',
    'work.title' : 'my title',
    'work.phone.mobile' : '123',
    'work.phone.work' : '456'
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ZMEmN/1/)

Comment: I still don't know which solution I will take yet. I'm still looking at both. Yes, I did not know that I could not accept multiple answers. I wish I could. But anyway, I really appreciated to all that can help me with quick answer.